# Remove character string from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, loops, replace, multiple-columns, rename

I have a large dataset with questionnaire data at multiple time points (waves). The questionnaire was identical at each point, so variables are labeled by time in the form "w#variablename" (e.g., "w1age", "w2age", "w3age").

I split the larger file into data frames by each time point, so I would now like to remove the "w#" from the column name for each column.

Basically, I would like to use R to "find and replace" to delete any column with "w1".

I split the data as follows:

```
w1 = Data %>% select(matches("w1"))
w2 = Data %>% select(matches("w2"))
w3 = Data %>% select(matches("w3"))
w4 = Data %>% select(matches("w4"))
```

Now for each of these 4 data sets, I would like to remove the respective "w#" from column names.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can use `rename_at`  without creating multiple objects `Data %>% rename_at(vars(matches("^w\\d+")), ~ str_remove(., "^w\\d+"))`

Comment: Do you want to _rename_ `w#` columns, or do you want to completely remove them?

Answer (score 5):

We should be able to use `sub` here:

```
names(Data) <- sub("^w\\d+", "", names(Data))
```

The regex pattern `^w\\d+` matches, at the start of each column name, `w`, followed by one or more digits.  We then replace this with empty string, effectively removing this prefix from matching column names.

Comment: That solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

An option with `tidyverse` would be `rename_at`.  Specify only the column names that needs to be changes with `matches` and with `str_remove` remove the substring "w" followed by one or more digits

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Data %>% 
   rename_at(vars(matches("^w\\d+")), ~ str_remove(., "^w\\d+"))
```

NOTE: If the column names are already `w1age`, `w2age` ... `w100age` and when we remove the 'w' followed by digits, all the columns would have the same column name which is discouraged).  So, probably, we may need to wrap with `make.unique` to make the column names unique

Comment: I think they are unique, since all columns should be in different data.frames, named accordingly to the wave they were collected in. I think the transformation should not be executed on `Data`, but rather on the resulting data.frames `w1`, `w2` and `w3`.